# Need to loop through 500+ table rows and browser is choking

Tags: jquery, loops

I've got a large table that lists out approximately 50 users and some simple data around their accounts, including the number of "projects" they have. When clicking on a user row more rows expand beneath to reveal detailed information about each of their projects. Most users have fewer than 20 projects, so it's not terribly taxing on the browser. However, there are a few users that have 100+ projects (one with 500+) and when clicking on the user row the browser stalls for anywhere from 1-4 seconds.

The table rows are set up so that any row with the `.project` class is hidden by default, and when clicking on a user row (no `.project` class) all subsequent rows with the `.project` class have the class `.open` added which displays them.

Suggestions on how to make this run faster? Is there a better, cleaner way to achieve the same effect?

Here is a simplified version of the HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td><td>Email</td><td>10 Projects</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="project">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Project Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="project">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Project Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="project">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Project Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="project">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Project Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="project">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Project Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="project">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Project Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="project">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Project Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="project">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Project Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="project">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Project Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="project">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Project Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td><td>Email</td><td>3 Projects</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="project">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Project Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="project">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Project Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="project">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Project Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

... and the JS:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.viewProjects = function() {

        this.each(function() {
            $(this).click(function(){

                var projects = $(this).nextUntil(':not(.project)'); // get all rows that follow and have the '.project' class

                if ($(this).hasClass('focused')) { // collapse
                    $(this).removeClass('focused');
                    projects.each(function(n, proj){
                        $(proj).removeClass('open');
                    });
                }
                else { // expand
                    $(this).addClass('focused');
                    projects.each(function(n, proj){
                        $(proj).addClass('open');
                    });
                }

            });
        });

    };

    $('tr:not(.project)').viewProjects();

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: have you considered or are you open to paging the results? so say, only show 20 user projects at a given time..

Comment: paginating is another solution - good idea @happytimeharry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the DOM is loading so much added stuff in to it. What I do in similar situations is:

- Check if there are more than 50 rows
- If so, then stop at 50 and place a "click to view more" link.
- When clicked, load the next 50 rows.
- Continue this process until all rows are loaded.

Alternatively, you can automatically trigger the next 50 rows to load when the user scrolls down the page. I prefer showing a link because automatically loading stuff can be confusing.

**Edit - What if you use jQuery to show and hide the contents instead of adding and removing a class each time?**

```
if ($(this).hasClass('focused')) { // collapse
    $(this).removeClass('focused');
    projects.hide();
} 
else { // expand
    $(this).addClass('focused');
    projects.show();
}
```

Comment: Does the same go for hiding, too? For instance, when clicking on the user with 500+ projects it takes approximately 2 seconds to display the projects. When clicking again to hide it takes almost as long. BTW, I'm not actually adding or removing from the DOM. I'm just changing a class that changes them from `position: absolute;` to `position: static;`.

Comment: It sounds like switching between absolute and static positioning is very processor intensive. I know that fixed positioning can be processor instensive.. Can you leave your elements as absolutely positioned, then toggle between jquery .show() and .hide() on the click event instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [webworker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker) to create threads to improve performance. I know this is a vague one, but i want to suggest this direction.

Unfortunately we cannot manipulate DOM inside webworkers. But DOM can be manipulated on your client code.

It appears that you are making XMLhttprequest to get new data, and this can be done inside webworkers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the each. the click function in Jquery is chainable This **may** speed it up:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.viewProjects = function() {

            $(this).click(function(){

                var projects = $(this).nextUntil(':not(.project)'); // get all rows that follow and have the '.project' class

                if ($(this).hasClass('focused')) { // collapse
                    $(this).removeClass('focused');
                    projects.each(function(n, proj){
                        $(proj).removeClass('open');
                    });
                }
                else { // expand
                    $(this).addClass('focused');
                    projects.each(function(n, proj){
                        $(proj).addClass('open');
                    });
                }

            });

    };

    $('tr:not(.project)').viewProjects();

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Be interested to know if it made any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing/hiding 500 items, show/hide one:

Restructure the HTML into something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td><td>Email</td><td>10 Projects</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="project">
        <td colspan="3">
            <ul>
                <li>Project Name</li>
                <li>Project Name</li>
                <li>Project Name</li>
                <li>Project Name</li>
                <li>Project Name</li>
                <li>Project Name</li>
                <li>Project Name</li>
                <li>Project Name</li>
                <li>Project Name</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I considered that but the project details need to align with the user details.

Comment: @BrandonDurham not sure what you mean by "the project details need to align with the user details" (visually? this can surely be accomplished with styling) but anytime you have HTML like this: `<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>` it's time to think about restructuring.

Comment: That was simplified sample code. I took out sensitive information and  replaced with `&nbsp;`.